# Having problems in storing string from startActivityFromResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent

What I want to do is:

1. When I launch the application, the main activity's interface will be
   shown but the Global String will have no data stored.
2. Then when I click the button in the MainActivity, I will be directed to the next Activity.
3. In this 2nd Activity, there is an EditText where I can input anything I want.
4. Then if done typing in the editText (lets assume EditText is the same as if-statement condition needed to execute), I will click the button in the 2nd Activity and pass the intent to the MainActivity class.
5. In the MainActivity, I want to get the intent passed by the 2nd Activity to store it in my String and when I click the button in MainActivity it will show a message that will display a toast saying "Successful".

My problem lies in step 5, when I click the button, it does not show "Successful"; it shows "Error". Assuming that I've typed what I want is the same as what I needed in the if-statement.

My Codes are:

**Floating Action Button Codes:**

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchCategory.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            }
        });
```

**Note:** This is the button that opens the 2nd Activity

**In my 2nd Activity button click codes:**

```
public void search(View view) {

    editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.start_text);
    type = editText1.getText().toString();



    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("type", type);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();

}
```

**The Button Click in Main Activity**

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
if (start == "Car") {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**On ActivityResult Codes:**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            /*EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_category);*/

            Bundle category = data.getExtras();
            category_text = category.getString("type");

            /*et.setText(start);*/
        }
    }
```

**Note:** I've tried adding an editText in main activity, it shows the text that I typed in the 2nd activity's editText.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832

Comment: "It show Error"... What is the value of the `start` variable when you click the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start is a String value so change this condition to

> start.equals("Car")

Answer (score 0):

Below code having a problem,

```
if (start == "Car") {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

You should compare your String with equals("Car")

Plz refere for some basic idea https://www.javatpoint.com/string-comparison-in-java

Answer (score 0):

1. When your `start` value changed? It`s never changed in this code. 
   In this case you should do this.

   `Bundle category = data.getExtras();
   start = category.getString("type");`
2. Or check condition by `category_text` like below

   `if (category_text.equals("Car")) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } else {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }`